# Concurrent reading of multiple files

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I am processing a my web server access logs and store the processed information into my db. Previously , I did as single threaded process. It took long time to complete the process. I decided to go with concurrent file reading to save the execution time. I achieved this using `Executors` thread pool. Here is my java code.

**Log File Handler**

```
class FileHandler implements Runnable {

        private File file;

        public FileHandler(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                byte[] readInputStream = readInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] readInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {

            //closing the bytearrayoutput stream has no effect. @see java doc.
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            bytesRead = in.read(buffer);

            //no input to read.
            if(bytesRead == -1) {
                    return null;
            }

            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(in.available()); //creating output stream with approximate capacity.
            bos.write(buffer , 0 , bytesRead);

            try {
                while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(buffer , 0 , bytesRead);
                }
            }finally {
                if(in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            }

            return bos.toByteArray();

         }


    }
```

**Concurrent File Reading**

```
 public class AccessLogProcessor {

        public static void main(String[] args)  {

            String[] files = {

                    "/home/local/ZOHOCORP/bharathi-1397/Downloads/unique-invoice-zuid1.txt" ,
                    "/home/local/ZOHOCORP/bharathi-1397/Downloads/unique-invoice-zuid.txt"

            };

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(files.length);

            for(String file : files) {
                executors.execute(new FileHandler(new File(file)));
            }

            executors.shutdown();

            while(!executors.isTerminated());

            System.out.println("Time Taken by concurrent reading :: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " ms ");

        }

}
```

**Single Threaded File Reading**

```
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {

            String[] files = {

                    "/home/local/ZOHOCORP/bharathi-1397/Downloads/unique-invoice-zuid1.txt" ,
                    "/home/local/ZOHOCORP/bharathi-1397/Downloads/unique-invoice-zuid.txt"

            };

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for(String file : files) {
                FileHandler.readInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            }

            System.out.println("Time Taken by concurrent reading :: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " ms ");

        }

}
```

**Test Result for 10 rounds of execution**

Single Thread Execution : 9ms.

Concurrent Execution : 14ms.

I am reading files in concurrently but why the timetaken is greater than single threaded execution?. Please correct me If I did anything wrong?.

Comment: look up context switching and contention of I/O resources; with a single physical disk, concurrent access will always slow down I/O

Comment: @JarrodRoberson , Can you please explain it briefly to get me out of this?.

Comment: what part of "look up `context switching and contention of I/O resources`" do you not understand? Google that exact phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I can see several problems:

1. Your test files seem to be extremely small and will be cached entirely in RAM, so your benchmark does not model the real problem because it does not take the I/O time into account. Also, because it is so small, any improvement you did get would probably be absorbed by the overhead of managing the threads.
2. Unless the data processing work that you do is quite complex, it's mainly an I/O-bound task, not a CPU-bound task, and unless your files are all on different disks, hassling one disk with simultaneous requests for different data is not going to make it work any faster. In fact, for traditional hard-disks rather than solid-state storage, "concurrent" I/O like this can be much slower, since the drive head ([the pointy arm thing](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Hard_disk_head_crash.jpg/1280px-Hard_disk_head_crash.jpg)) will be madly flicking back and forth to get to the different parts of the disk.
3. The accuracy of `System.currentTimeMillis()` is +/- 10 milliseconds on most systems. So, your benchmark results of 9 ms and 14 ms  *don't actually tell you anything at all*. Use `System.nanoTime()` for a more accurate timer.
4. How many times did you run the code? Apparently only once each time you ran the program. If it was less than thousands of times, you didn't measure anything useful at all because the code was still compiling. Don't feel bad: everyone makes that mistake! Benchmarking in dynamically compiled languages is ***damn hard***. To learn how to write useful benchmarks, read:

   - [Dynamic compilation and performance measurement](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/)
   - [Anatomy of a flawed microbenchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/)

   At the least, you should run your complete code in a loop many times so that it takes *seconds* to complete, not milliseconds.
5. On frequency switching CPUs (i.e., modern ones), the CPU is running underclocked when idle. Only once it starts doing work will it gradually kick up the speed, and this can muddle up benchmarks unless you set it into a fixed speed (max battery or max performance) mode. Alternatively, fixing problem 4 will fix problem 5, because using long loops or adding warmup code will absorb the effect of the CPU's frequency switching.

The short answer is that your current benchmark is **too small** to give meaningful results. Once you've run a longer benchmark which more accurately models the real problem, you'll be able to know if multithreading makes it faster or not.

Comment: I like your answer. It says everything my answer did (except adding the "disk cache" extra point). All the more so it is surprising why it is not attacked by the company of idiots. You are cool.

Answer (score -1):

At first, you should understand that parallelism applies to series of instructions executed by processors. A processor executes a series of instructions. The virtual processors are called `threads`. You may allocate multiple threads to execute multiple instructions in parallel. But, this does not mean that multiprocessing allows you to download movies faster over your network connection, multiplying the bandwidth. This means that your parallel threads will be paused waiting for the network data to arrive. OK? We should do something with people not understanding this simple thing.

Additionally, I must add that 10 ms is the time measurement error in java. So, your readings are the time measurement noise. Benchmarking needs some time for the system to heat up and take longer intervals so that timer resolution would not introduce significant error.

Comment: this is wrong on some many fronts it is sad.

Comment: to start with this is fundamentally wrong as to render the entire rest of the answer wrong as well. *"The virtual processors are called threads"*

Comment: To start with, if you think that this statement is wrong, you do not know what Executor (the thread pool is). Thread pool = pool of processors. Secondly, I am waiting to hear other fronts that are "wrong" because of that.

Comment: Thread pool http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173575/what-is-a-thread-pool

Comment: Thanks, cap. It also says that those threads execute the code submitted to them for execution. How do you call those physical entities that execute your code? How do you call the hardware that is simulated in software?